# Como acceder a un archivo rdlc desde el ViewModel utilizando MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de escritorio en la cual se generan pdf's. Para generar el pdf utilizo un archivo `rdlc` el cual contiene el diseño del pdf. Este archivo esta localizado en una carpeta dentro de un proyecto, el path de este archivo sería así:`C:\Users\User\Documents\proyect\Proyect.View\Modulo\PDF.rdlc`.

Para crear el pdf, utilizo un método el cual necesita como parametro el path del rldc. La llamada al metodo se ve así:

```
generarReceta.Receta(
                     "..\\..\\Modulo\\PDF.rdlc",
                     "RecetaMedica",
                     NombrePaciente,
                     registro.NUM_OFICIO,
                     receta.FECHA.ToString(),
                     receta.OBSERVACIONES,
                     NombreDoctor,
                     CedulaDoctor,
                     receta.PADECIMIENTOS,
                     Meds,
                     receta.FOLIO,
                     NoEmpleado,
                     codigoBarras
                );
```

Como podrán ver, retrocedo dos carpetas para llegar a la carpeta dónde se encuentra el rdlc. El problema de esto es que funciona cuando ejecuto la aplicación desde el Visual Studio, pero cuando quiero generar un archivo instalable y creo el ejecutable de la aplicación, marca error porque al parecer las rutas no son validas cuando la aplicación es un ejecutable. 
He tratado de agregar el rdlc a los Resources de el proyecto Proyect.View, y utilizar una ruta como la siguiente: 
`pack://application:,,,/Resources/PDF.rdlc` pero no encuentra el archivo y el programa lanza error.
Como puedo hacer que encuentre el archivo rdlc?

Answer (score 0):

Se debe a que la ruta es relativa al fichero del ejecutable.

Cuando compilas el proyecto, el `.exe` se va a generar en la carpeta configurada (el *outputDir*). De ahí, la ruta relativa `..\..\Modulo\PDF.rdcl` será diferente de cuando lo ejecutas directamente des de *Visual Studio*.

Lo que debes hacer es incluir esta dependencia al proyecto para que se haga una copia cuando compiles el proyecto.

Primero, mueve la carpeta `Modulo`(junto con el fichero) al mismo nivel donde se encuentre tu `csproj`.
Ahora, en el `csproj` debes añadir lo siguiente

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="Modulo\" />
  <Content Include="Modulo\PDF.rdlc">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Esto va a hacer una copia de la carpeta `Modulo` al directorio donde se compile e incluirá el fichero `rdlc` dentro de la misma carpeta.

Ahora, en tu código ya podrás usar una ruta relativa

```
generarReceta.Receta(
    Path.Combine("Modulo", "PDF.rdlc"),
    // ...
);
```

`Path.Combine(params string[])` te permite crear rutas de ficheros *cross-platform* (es decir, que sirvan en cualquier sistema operativo).

Espero que sirva.